# I don't see data older than 72h

Tags: grafana, graphite, graphite-carbon, whisper

i have problem with my graphite (I think so)
when i set eg. CPU-system diagram to 72h is all ok, i see data etc.
when i set more than 72 - eg. 73 or 73-89h from this moment i see empty graph 
I can't even see the latest data 72h

I try change storage-schemas.conf eg.

```
[default_1min_for_2weeks]
pattern = .*
retentions = 10s:100h,5m:168d,10m:1y
```

I try change by this option

```
find /var/lib/carbon/whisper-ng/* -type f -name '*.wsp' -exec whisper-resize --nobackup {} 10s:100h 5m:160d 10m:1y \;  -exec chown carbon:carbon \;
```

but sometimes it help, but not for long after couple days problem is back

Interestingly, it works normally on some charts (all data from collectd)

Graphite-web 1.2.0DEV
go-carbon 0.13.0